# Humminbird echosounder multicast stream data to listen c#

Tags: c#, stream, multicast, helix

Good day firends

I am trying to write app  for my echosounder humminbird helix 9 to live receive  data from it.
I have connected  it  by router  and  using wire shark  i found that  it streams  data by multicast :
side scan row data stream,  gps stream, sonar stream. Please find attached
[image]
Up to now  i  find out how to receive frames to  my  app, but i can not manage to take over  multi cast stream read.
For example to  read gps data [image]

Do you have any clue how to connect to multi cast stream and take data from it?. Like  from above screen gps data .

Best regards

If any body have an idea  how to manage this  problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I've been messing around with the same stuff that you are.

What i've discovered thus far is that there are 2 ways that these units share data on the network. For more simple data sources (GPS), you need to estabilish a TCP connection described by the SLP exchanges you are seeing broadcast.

For sonar data, you need to send a TCP message to the service listening on a particular port to tell the unit to start multicasting data. You'd then be able to see UDP packets if you open up a socket on the port specified in the SLP exchanges (joining the multicast address also specified by the SLP exchanes).

Essentially step one is to get a basic SLP/SRVCLOC client/user agent set up and then go from there.